# Storing Values in Pig

Tags: apache-pig, storage

I have a file with variables description, totalamt, year, and type.

If the year is 2000, and a certain type, I want to store these fields for later use.

If the year is greater than 2000 I want to find the increase percentage 
from the year 2000 value.  I have seen the replicate but not sure how it is used.

```
mysales = load 'hdfs:/user/derezone_yahoo/retailsales.txt' using PigStorage(' ')    AS (saledesc:chararray,totsales:int,salesyear:chararray,adjtype:chararray);
baseamt = FOREACH mysales GENERATE IF salesyear=='2000' then join totalsales by 0 using replicated;
```

> this statement fails on the  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or
>   near 'salesyear'

what is the syntax error? I've put it in parentheses and still errors out

also is my replicate statement correct to store the totalamt in baseamt?

The data is structured in year order (i.e. 2000, 2001,2002 etc)

Answer (score 0):

Foreach doesn't accept if-else conditions the way you have put there.
In your case , Try something like this:

```
mysales = load 'hdfs:/user/derezone_yahoo/retailsales.txt' using PigStorage(' ')    AS (aledesc:chararray,totsales:int,salesyear:chararray,adjtype:chararray);
B = FILTER mysales BY salesyear=='2000'; 
C = JOIN B BY  .... (Your conditions)
```

See more on joins [here](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#JOIN+%28inner%29) :